# Python multiprocessing performance degradation

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I've written a Python script, using the `multiprocessing` and `subprocess` modules, to run 8 (`multiprocessing.cpu_count()`) Java processes at a time in parallel.

Some relevant code (redacted for brevity):

```
class Task(object):
    def __init__(self, inputfile):
        self.inputfile = inputfile
        self.command = ['java', '-jar', 'process.jar', '-dir', inputfile]

    def execute(self):
        subprocess.call(self.command)

        # clear unused memory
        subprocess.check_output('sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches', shell=True)


class Consumer(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, taskqueue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.taskqueue = taskqueue

    def run(self):
        proc_name = self.name
        while True:
            task = self.taskqueue.get()
            if task is None:
                self.taskqueue.task_done()
                break

            task.execute()
            self.taskqueue.task_done()

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        return

    taskqueue = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    num_consumers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    consumers = [Consumer(taskqueue) for i in xrange(num_consumers)]
    folders = [f for f in os.listdir(sys.argv[1]) if '.' not in f]

    for c in consumers:
        c.start()

    for folder in folders:
        taskqueue.put(Task(sys.argv[1] + folder))

    for i in xrange(num_consumers):
        taskqueue.put(None)

    taskqueue.join()
```

There are 2800 files in total that need to processed so this is a quite a lengthy process and I expect it to take several days to complete. All of them are added to the `JoinableQueue`. Initially, all 8 processes do equal amount of work but after a while, judging by the log output, it seems like only one is doing the work. This is also apparent by the number of outputs generated per hour. However, checking `top` shows that all 8 process are using a 100% of their respective core. This seems odd and I'm having trouble understanding what is going on.

This is being run on an AWS instance with 68GB of RAM and an 8-core cpu.

Comment: I think the 100% here means, each process consume the 100% of the respective core.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda yes, and they are all java processes.

Comment: Maybe the Queue stays with a minimum of 1 job for some reason?

Comment: If this is a quirk of the `multiprocessing` module, note that you could as well use `threading`. The actual work is done in subprocesses anyway.

Comment: @JanneKarila you make a good point which I seemed to have overlooked.

Comment: Are the (sub)processes in some way I/O bound? I see this type of stuff when you exhaust a cache and I/O can no longer keep up with the CPU (especially if there's some type of busy wait going on).

Comment: @Livius Yes, I think they are. A process opens and reads a file which could be between 15MB - 40MB in size. It also writes to a different output file which could end up growing to the same size as the input file. I switched to using the `threading` module instead but there is no change.